# Integrability of $f(x,y)=(1-x)^{a}$ on $D=\{(x,y):0<x^2+y^2<1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, solution-verification

As it is said in the title, I need to check the integrability of $$f(x,y)=(1-x)^{a}$$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}$ on the open disk $D= \{0<x^2+y^2<1\}.$

**My attempt**

- Let $a \geq 0,$ then since $D \subset [-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ is bounded and $f$ is bounded on $D$ we have $f_{a\geq 0}\in L^1(D).$
- Let $a<0.$ Then since $x \neq 0$ on $D,$ $f_a$ is continous on $D$ and thus measurable. But it is also unbounded for $(x,y)\to (1,0).$ I use polar coordinates and evaluate $$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^1(1-\rho \cos\theta)^a \rho \ d\rho$$
  Changing variable $\rho \mapsto \rho\cos\theta=t,$ $\ t'=\cos\theta$, we have $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{cos^2\theta}d\theta \int_0^{\cos\theta}(1-t)^at \ dt$$
  Then I can evaluate $$\int_0^{cos\theta}t \ dt-\int_0^{cos\theta}t^{a+1} \ dt=\frac{1}{2}\cos^2\theta-\int_0^{cos\theta}t^{a+1} \ dt$$ and $$\int_0^{cos\theta}t^{a+1} \ dt < +\infty \iff -1<a+1 \iff -2<a$$ in which case it remains to check that
  $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}-\frac{(\cos\theta)}{2}^{a+2}=\pi-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(\cos\theta)}{a+2}^{a+2}\ d\theta<+\infty$$

> So, to conclude, $f_a \in L^1(D) \iff -2<a $.
>
> Do you agree? Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: $f$ is Riemann integrable on $D$ since the boundary of $D$ has measure 0.

Comment: @PankajTiwari Your comment does not make any sense

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you leave out $(0,0)$ in the integral. Your function $f$ is continuous on $\{x^2+y^2<1\}$ no matter what $a$ is.

The integral can be written

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt {1-x^2}}^{\sqrt {1-x^2}}\,dy\,(1-x)^a\,dx = \int_{-1}^1 2\sqrt {1-x^2}(1-x)^a\,dx$$ $$=\int_{-1}^1 2\sqrt {1+x}\sqrt {1-x}(1-x)^a\,dx =\int_{-1}^1 2\sqrt {1+x}(1-x)^{a+1/2}\,dx.$$

Now the integral from $-1$ to $0 $ converges no matter what $a$ is. Let's forget about it. And on $[0,1],$ $2\sqrt {1+x}$ lies between $2$ and $2\sqrt 2,$ so it has no impact on convergence/divergence. We're left thinking about

$$\int_{0}^1 (1-x)^{a+1/2}\,dx.$$

That converges iff $a+1/2>-1,$ or $a>-3/2.$

Comment: you are right about the $0$. I wanted to say $x\neq 1$ and $0 \leq x^2 + y^2$. I will edit

Comment: But apart from that then what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: Using polar coordinates seems to give an easier integral than yours

Comment: Can you elaborate your solution or point to an error in mine? If you could do both would be extremely helpful. thanks

Comment: Your mistake is claiming $(1-t)^at = t-t^{a+1}.$

Comment: I edited my answer to a more complete solution.

Comment: Jesus you are right. Do you think there is a way to save my attempt, and proceed from where I made the error?

Comment: Also, I do understand why we don't have to worry about convergence on $[-1,0].$

Comment: Ok I get it, because for $x\in [-1,0]$ the function is bounded. Right?

Comment: Right. As for salvaging your proof, I don't know. Polar coordinates seems to complicate the situation in my view.